# Expectation of real zeroes of random algebraic polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, polynomials

I am currently working on calculating the expectation of real zeroes of random n-th degree algebraic polynomials with independently and identically distributed random variables as coefficients. That is, the expectation of real zeroes for:
$$X_0 + X_1x+X_2x^2 +X_3x^3+...+X_{n-1}x^{n-1}$$
M. Kac had tackled this problem for $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ in his paper in [1943](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1943-49-04/S0002-9904-1943-07912-8/S0002-9904-1943-07912-8.pdf). However, I am trying to extend his results to the random coefficients following a t-distribution or a Laplace distribution. In seeing the tedious calculations through for each case (both the Laplace and the t-distribution), it turns out that the expectation of real zeroes that I am getting is exactly the same as that of Kac - for both distributions.

I was just wondering if this intuitively makes sense. Since all three distributions have a different probability density function, this seems rather counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: "Algebraic" is a confusing term in this context since it sounds like you might be asking for the coefficients to be algebraic numbers. Just saying "polynomials" is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have an intuitive take: Since the zeros of a polynomial are independent of the scale of the polynomial (e.g. the roots of $\lambda P(x)$ are the same as $P(x)$), then polynomials with coefficients distributed as $N(0,1)$ have the same root distribution as the $N(0, \lambda)$ distribution. Hence any distribution that can be decomposed into a weighted sum of zero mean Gaussians should have the same root distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own take on the intuitive, heuristic reason behind that universality:

**1.** As in the remark of the paper, most of the zero of the polynomial will concentrate toward $\pm 1$.

**2.** Let $1 \ll q \ll L$ be large positive integers. For $x \approx 1$ and with $n = Lq$, we have $\log n \sim \log L$ and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k x^k
&= \sqrt{q} \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{q}} \sum_{r=0}^{q-1} X_{lq+r} x^{r} \right) (x^q)^l \\
&\approx \sqrt{q} \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} Y_l (x^q)^l,
\end{align*}
where $Y_l = \frac{1}{\sqrt{q}} \sum_{r=0}^{q-1} X_{lq+r}$ are i.i.d. and approximately normal.

This suggests that Kac's result, which was originally established for i.i.d. normal coefficients, may remain valid for coefficients with more general distributions.